# Calculate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ ($n!e-[n!e]$)?

Tags: limits, factorial, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Calculate 
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (n!e-[n!e])$$

I think that  it will be  $\infty $ as $\lim_{n \to \infty} (n!e-[n!e])= \infty -  \infty =  \infty $.

Is it True/false  ??

Comment: What exactly do you denote with $[\cdot]$?

Comment: Greatest integer  functions @mrtaurho

Comment: Seeing as $x-[x]$ is always between $0$ and $1$, I don't think your limit is anywhere near infinity. @Messififa

Comment: okks  let  me thinks  one more  @LordSharktheUnknown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From $\text{e}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\,\frac{1}{k!}$, we have
$$n!\,\text{e}=\sum_{k=0}^n\,\frac{n!}{k!}+\epsilon_n\,,$$
where
$$\epsilon_n:=\sum_{k>n}\,\frac{n!}{k!} < \sum_{k>n}\,\frac{1}{(n+1)^{k-n}}=\frac{1}{n}\,.$$
That is,
$$\lfloor n!\,\text{e}\rfloor =\sum_{k=0}^n\,\frac{n!}{k!}\text{ and }n!\,\text{e}-\lfloor n!\,\text{e}\rfloor=\epsilon_n\,.$$
Clearly, $\epsilon_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

Clearly $n!e-[n!e]$ is a number between $0$ and $1$, so the limit, if it exists, is also a number between $0$ and $1$. So it is not $\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

Note: $e= \sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i!}$.

If you multiply by $n!$, then the terms in the sum corresponding to the indices $i=0, 1, \ldots, n$ become integers, so the do not contribute to the fractional part.

So the answer is the same as $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum\limits_{i=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{i!}$.

It is easy to show that the sum $\sum\limits_{i=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{i!}$ is at most $\frac{1}{n}$. So the limit is 0.